How do I late bind excel in vb project targeting .Net 7.0?
I have to late bind to excel for a project because the project will be used in an environment with users utilizing several different versions of Office. In VB projects targeting .Net Framework (say, 4.7.2, for example), the following works without issue:
            Dim myExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            myExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
            myExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
            myExcelApp.Visible = False
            Dim myExcelWb As New Object
            myExcelWb = myExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
            myExcelWb.Sheets.Add()
            Dim myExcelWs As New Object
            myExcelWs = myExcelWb.Sheets(1)

but in a VB project targeting .Net (7.0) such a pattern fails because myExcelApp is returned as a System.__ComObject instead of a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass, and all of the properties and methods of the System.__ComObject returned show up in the "dynamic view" instead of being public
The error received from trying to run this code in a .NET 7.0 project is "Public member 'DisplayAlerts' on type 'Application' not found." (-2146233070), which makes sense given that all of the properties and methods are in the "dynamic view" of the object.
Is there a way to make .NET 7.0 behave like .NET Framework 4.7.2, or am I going to be forced to deal with trying to work with these dynamic properties and methods?  If I have to deal with the dynamics, where do I start?

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/90541

Following through the link posted by Hans, it looks like this is resolved in .NET 8 (and later).  I wouldn't expect it to be resolved in any earlier versions, especially not an odd-numbered version which is likely out-of-support soon.

I think you're stuck with either targeting .NET 8 or moving to early binding by adding a reference to a specific version of the Excel interop COM type library. I got your code to work with .NET 6 by adding a COM reference and explicitly typing myExcelApp.

If you are doing simple Excel automation, such as filling in a worksheet with data, I'd recommend using EPPlus instead. It's much easier to use than Office automation, and it will be distributed with your app, so no dependencies on various Excel versions.
